# Failed to register a ServiceWorker (Flutter)

Tags: web, flutter, dart, service-worker

I'm working on a Flutter Web App and today I got these errors:

> A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a
>   ServiceWorker for scope ('https://adrieldf.github.io/') with script
>   ('https://adrieldf.github.io/flutter_service_worker.js'): A bad HTTP
>   response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

The only thing "different" that I added to the code was a dependency for the Share library, but I don't think that that is the problem.

Here is the interesting thing, I've got the app hosted on Github Pages and after every commit I have a action that builds the web app. After the build, when I try to access it doesn't load and the errors appears. But building it and running it locally works normally.

Here is the source code if you want to check: https://github.com/Adrieldf/allthewidgets
The website link is in the repo description.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem by changing the index.html file

from
`<base href="/">`

to
`<base href="/directory_name/">`

Answer (score 2):

Looks, like you are trying to run the project from the `project_root/web` folder.

If you just start a webserver here (for example, by using `python -m http.server 8088`), the application will start and even will be working partially.

But compiled web app located in `project_root/build/web`. Try to run your webserver in that folder.

Comment: Thank you!  This indeed fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by
changing base tag inside build/web/index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="./">
```

added . (dot)

Answer (score 0):

For me got resolved simply after upgrading flutter packages:

```
flutter packages upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter create .

flutter build web
```

and use the `project/build/web` as server's location

Answer (score 0):

you can use [peanut](https://pub.dev/packages/peanut) to build your flutter app and copy it to gh-pages project using something like:

```
peanut --extra-args "--base-href=/directory-name/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing base tag inside build/web/index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

to
added . (dot) with the folder name inside which i added my flutter build

```
<base href="./flutter/portfolio">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your PC web  and Mobile web  are different, you can try to upload flutter_ service_ worker.js in your PC web

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Well, the problem is what the error message says. Your JS is trying to register a Service Worker from the script 'https://adrieldf.github.io/flutter_service_worker.js' but that does not exist on the server. If you open that URL it's a 404.

Comment: yeah but the file is on the root of the branch that is hosted on github pages. https://github.com/Adrieldf/allthewidgets/tree/gh-pages (this one) and the file is generated automatically by the workflow that builds the web app.
Maybe it is a problem with flutter?

Comment: @Adriel I wouldn't say that it's a problem with Flutter. There's a problem in some configuration of the various build tools used which causes the Service Worker script file to be located in a place that is different to the one the app expects.